# What happens if you get lost while rescuing Jenny?

Tags: robinson-crusoe

In scenario 3 of Robinson Crusoe, your task is to build a raft to rescue Jenny, and then build a lifeboat to escape your deserted island before a hurricane arrives. (Let us not consider the wisdom of "sailing through a hurricane in a cobbled-together lifeboat" too much.) Until you rescue Jenny, she takes some damage every round; after you rescue her, she does nothing but rest and eat your food.

As a result of Jenny's terrible post-rescue utility, my last game involved abandoning Jenny for quite some time before getting around to constructing a raft. As it happened, she had exactly one wound remaining when we rescued her, and we rolled the dice and got a random event when we did. The random event was "you're lost and will be outside the camp tonight."

**Does this mean Jenny is outside the camp, or could she plausibly have returned to the camp while you remain lost?** (In this case, being outside the camp would cause 3 wounds: 1 from lack of shelter, and 2 from lack of food.)

(The first explanation is the most obvious, but I argued for the second on the theory that Jenny is, in every important way, a separate character, and that the event happened to the character who explored, rather than to Jenny.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that there is room for interpretation. Clearly, once Jenny **is** in the camp she is affected from cards effects, weather, having no shelter etc. However, I would say that Jenny **is not** in the camp in your situation, but neither on the rock. Remember that if a character has to spend the night outside of the camp, then all the resources he got in his action are not available for the whole group, but only for the character himself. So in this case I would say that Jenny is kind of a gathered resource.

It happens often in the game that you run in situations like this. As a rule of thumb, take the action that does the most harm.

Comment: The response from Jonas Svedas is actually correct. The "raft" item has ? = wound on it, indicating that if you are rolling to try to rescue her and get a question mark, you take a wound instead of drawing a card.

Answer (score 2):

When you roll the dice for the exploration action, the question mark result equates to a life lost- this is explained on the scenario card.
So you cannot get lost and spend the night outside while rescuing her.